# Docker: manage image build dependencies

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

I work with a private Docker registry. Inside, there are several images, each built from Dockerfile. All images can be sorted using the dependencies as hierarchy.

The Dockerfiles are stocked inside a GitHub repository, and are built through a Jenkinsfile.

Example:

- Image-1: built from `node:10-alpine`
- Image-2: built from `Image-1`
- Image-3: built from `golang:1.11.2-alpine3.8`
- Image-4: built from `Image-2` & `Image-3`

The need now is to successfully parallelize the image build when possible, and to build the images following the hierarchy. So:

- First build: `Image-1` & `Image-3`
- Second build: `Image-2`
- Third & last build: `Image-4`

The questions are now:

- How can we parallelize the images build?
- How can we build the docker images following the hierarchy?
- How can we know the hierarchy when we only have the Dockerfile for each image?

Thanks for reading.
Have a nice day

Comment: Which buildtool are you using? Typically you can set some kind of trigger for each pipeline to preserve order and make sure dependent images are rebuild.

Comment: The Dockerfile are stocked inside a specific GitHub repository. This repo has one Jenkinsfile to build all images (we are looking to patch this part too).